# Get latest record from a subset in a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two related tables.

```
Table 1:
recordid | OrderNumber | MobileNumber
       1 | 1234        | 9999999999
       2 | 1234        | 9888888888
       3 | 1234        | 9777777777
       4 | 5433        | 9666666666
       5 | 1444        | 9555555555
       6 | 1444        | 9444444444
       7 | 1544        | 9333333333
       8 | 1632        | 9222222222


Table 2
recordid | modifiedon
       1 | 15/1/2013
       2 | 17/1/2013 
       3 | 13/1/2013
       4 | 10/1/2013
       5 | 16/1/2013
       6 | 01/1/2013 
       7 | 09/1/2013
       8 | 08/1/2013
```

what i want to do is get a unique set of `OrderNumber` and their corresponding `MobileNumbers`. If there is are more than one record for one `OrderNumber`, then the query should get `OrderNumber` and `MobileNumber` of the latest modified record.

So basically i should get the following result.

```
OrderNumber | MobileNumber
1234        | 9888888888
5433        | 9666666666
1444        | 9555555555
1544        | 9333333333
1632        | 9222222222
```

i have tried

```
select OrderNumber, MobileNumber from Table1 
where OrderNumber in 
(
   Select Distinct table1. rderNumber, table2.ModifiedOn 
   from Table1, Table2 
   group by table2.ModifiedOn desc
)
```

This is urgent and I would be very greatly to receive quick responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier with a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT t1.ordernumber, 
        t1.mobilenumber, 
        RN = Row_number() 
               OVER ( 
                 partition BY t1.ordernumber 
                 ORDER BY t2, modifiedon DESC) 
         FROM   table1 t1 
                INNER JOIN table2 t2 
                        ON t1.recordid = t2.recordid) 
SELECT ordernumber, 
       mobilenumber
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Apart from that, you had a  `DESC` after a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: i have tried using that as well, but i dont get the desired result. i get all the records

Comment: I have used Order BY.. sorry that was my bad!!

Comment: this query takes a very long time to execute.. is there any other way around to get the result faster?

Comment: Have you an index on `OrderNumber` **and** `ModifiedOn`? `CREATE INDEX idxOrderNumModified ON table1(ordernumber, modifiedon desc);`

Comment: @SPG13: I mean, no separate indices but a composite, have you seen my edited comment?

Comment: This worked like a charm.. i had a slow connection. works faster on dev server.. thank u!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from 
(
select t1.*, 
       row_number() 
       over (PARTITION BY t1.OrderNumber 
             ORDER BY t2.modifiedon DESC ) as rn
from t1
left join t2 on (t1.recordid=t2.recordid)
)
where RN=1
```